# Why does a template binding to a controller function update but not a binding to a variable?

Tags: angularjs

Here is the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gEuZoLxyOLZuTb4CMZGV?p=preview

Why does {{ foo() }} update after the timeout but not {{ number }}
They are calling the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `$scope.number = return_zero($scope.bool);` on creation. So `$scope.number` is 1, and this never changes throughout your code. The part that is watching the function will evaluate the function on every digest. So when you change `$scope.bool`  to false in the timeout, a digest will occur and the function will be evaluated. It returns 0 so it updates that part of the dom, but `$scope.number` is still 1.

Hope this helped!

Comment: To expand on this answer: if you want a variable to update you can use the `$scope.$watch('bool',function(newBool,oldBool){$scope.number = return_zero(newBool)});` to reassign number whenever bool changes

Comment: As I understand it, a digest loop iterates over all watchers and calls them. So, is {{ foo() }} adding foo() to the watchers array?

Comment: usin `{{foo()}}` the function is evaluated and all scope variables inside it are watched for changes as these will require the function to be re-evaluated. {{number}} is also watched but it is assigned the value returned by return_zero(), not the function itself.